# Qual o melhor lugar para guardar a string de conexão?

Tags: c#, .net, banco-de-dados, ado.net, connectionstring

Existem alguns lugares possíveis para se armazenar a *string* de conexão.
Deixar amarrado dentro do código, `app.config`, arquivo de configuração e registro do Windows.

Qual o melhor lugar para armazenar a *string* de conexão? Baseado nos quesitos, segurança, desempenho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O melhor é ter a configuração básica no [`app.config`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (eventualmente `web.config`) e não colocar senhas nela.

Mas se o fizer, que faça usando criptografia. Colocar senhas expostas, especialmente, é uma temeridade. É melhor usar [autenticação integrada com o sistema operacional](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/protecting-connection-information?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) ou autenticação feita com usuário e senha solicitado na aplicação e não disponível em qualquer lugar dela.

É claro que algumas situações pode pedir uma solução diferente.

Feito isso será seguro até onde pode ser seguro. A performance não é relevante para isso, se não fizer nenhuma maluquice, mas nem os piores programadores costumam fazer maluquices com isso.

Comment: Estou deletando o comentário, era pouca coisa para corrigir nem ia me permitir fazer a correção.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode armazenar as suas **connection strings** no seu **app.config** , tendo em conta que isto envolve riscos de segurança, aconselho a ler  o seguinte artigo, que nos ajuda a ter uma boa prática: 
[ConnectionStrings - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx)

Você pode também encriptar a sua string de conexão e continuar a armazená-la da mesma forma, no mesmo ficheiro de configuração.